# Embedded Database Content Alternate Rows only showing

Tags: php, embed

When I add the following line to code to display my database content the database only shows odd numbered rows

```
<td>" ."<iframe  width=150 height=150 src=\"". $row['Video_Address'] ."\"   alt=\"\"\ /</iframe>". "</td>
```

Here is the code which will work if the offending line is removed. Since the page has 200 lines altogether it is not suitable to show the entire page.

```
echo '<table style="display: inline-block"><table width="2500" border="0"  align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">';
echo "<table border='1'>
<table bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
    <tr>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Theme</th>
        <th>Full Page<br>Associated<br>with Video</th>
        <th>Video<br>Address</th>
        <th>Associated<br>Comments</th>
        <th>Associated<br>Quiz</th>
        <th>Creator</th>  
</tr>";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
   if ($color == 1) {
       echo "<tr bgcolor='#708020'>
        <td>" . $row['MyOrder'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['Theme'] . "</td>
        <td><a href=". 'Videos.php?Videos_Name='.$row['Videos_Name'].'&Videos_Name='.$row['Videos_Name'].' "</a>'.$row['Videos_Name']."</td>
        <td>" ."<iframe  width=150 height=150 src=\"". $row['Video_Address'] ."\" alt=\"\"\ /</iframe>". "</td>
        <td>" . $row['Associated_Comments'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['Associated_Quiz'] . "</td>
        <td>" ."<img src=\"". $row['Avatar'] ."\" alt=\"\" />"."</br><p align='center'><a href=". 'Member_Profile.php?username='.$row['Creator'].' "</a>'.$row['Creator']."</td>
        </tr>";

         $color = "2";
    } else {
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#BFB7C7'>
        <td>" . $row['MyOrder'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['Theme'] . "</td>
        <td><a href=". 'Videos.php?Videos_Name='.$row['Videos_Name'].'&Videos_Name='.$row['Videos_Name'].' "</a>'.$row['Videos_Name']."</td>
        <td>" ."<iframe  width=150 height=150 src=\"". $row['Video_Address'] ."\" alt=\"\"\ /</iframe>". "</td>
        <td>" . $row['Associated_Comments'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['Associated_Quiz'] . "</td>
        <td>" ."<img src=\"". $row['Avatar'] ."\" alt=\"\" />"."</br><p align='center'><a href=". 'Member_Profile.php?username='.$row['Creator'].' "</a>'.$row['Creator']."</td>
        </tr>";

        $color="1";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Can't think of an obvious explanation as to why only odd numbered rows should display. I can always remove it, but like to understand why something will not work. Hope someone can assist. Also doesn't work when I get rid of alternate row colouring code and use one colour display mode.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason which I can't explain, I have added the errant code in twice, so that it reads, and hey presto I get both odd an even numbers, without the duplication of having two columns side by side containing the same embedded videos twice. I'd still love an explanation, but at least the page works! :)

```
<td>" ."<iframe  width=150 height=150 src=\"". $row['Video_Address'] ."\"    alt=\"\"\ /</iframe>". "</td>
<td>" ."<iframe  width=150 height=150 src=\"". $row['Video_Address'] ."\" alt=\"\"\ /</iframe>". "</td>
```